# Functional solution for short path algorithm in Python

Tags: python, shortest-path

I am reading [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good!](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) and found out interesting puzzle. I decided to implement it in Python in a most functional way.
[image: short path map]

Please see my code:

```
def open_file():
    file_source = open('resource/path.txt', 'r') # contains 50\n 10\n 30\n 5\n 90\n 20\n 40\n 2\n 25\n 10\n 8\n 0\n
    return file_source


def get_path_tuple(file_source, pathList=[]):
    try:
        node = int(next(file_source)), int(next(file_source)), int(next(file_source))
        pathList.append(node)
        get_path_tuple(file_source, pathList)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return pathList


def short_step(pathList, n, stepList):
    try:
        stepA = pathList[n][0] + pathList[n][1]
        stepB = pathList[n][1] + pathList[n][2]
        stepList.append(min([stepA, stepB]))
        short_step(pathList, n+1, stepList)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return stepList


pathList = get_path_tuple(open_file(), [])
pathList.reverse()
print(short_step(pathList, 0, []))
```

But I hit into problem, I don't know how to keep state of current location. Result is: `[8, 27, 95, 40]`. 
Could you please help to fix my code.

Comment: Just a quick note, be careful with that `pathList=[]` in your `get_path_tuple`. You are setting it to an empty list which is mutable, and default argument values are evaluated only once at function definition time, so modifying it inside the function will affect all subsequent calls to that function. Put a print statement in the first line of the function and call it many times and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, and using your data structure, it seems that you should be able to run two scenarios in parallel:

- Cost of A
- Cost of B

You can maintain a current cost, and the data you collect provides a "cost to switch" in the third element.

So you need to ask: which is cheaper? Staying on the starting path, or switching over to the other path?

```
path_list = [
        (50, 10, 30),
        (5, 90, 20),
        (40, 2, 25),
        (10, 8, 0),
]

A = 0
B = 1
Switch = 2

def cheapest_path(path_list, path=None, history=None):
    if history is not None:
        # Terminate when path_list is empty
        if not path_list:
            return history

        # Determine cost to stay this path, vs. cost to switch
        step = path_list[0]
        path_list = path_list[1:]

        stay_on_path = cheapest_path(path_list, path, history + [step[path]])
        switch_path = cheapest_path(path_list, B if path == A else A, history + [step[path], step[Switch]])

        return switch_path if sum(switch_path) < sum(stay_on_path) else stay_on_path
    else:

        pathA = cheapest_path(path_list, A, [])
        pathB = cheapest_path(path_list, B, [])
        return pathA if sum(pathA) < sum(pathB) else pathB

print(", ".join(map(str, cheapest_path(path_list))))
```

Comment: a very beautiful solution. How did you do it? Is there any puzzles/books for improvement  "recursive intuition"?

Comment: This solution falls directly out of the way you chose to store the data. It was actually somewhat counter-intuitive to me, since my inclination was to switch paths before adding the cost of the current step.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think that as in all pathfinding problems, you have to compute the total path length from start to every point. Then you have to compute both, list of path to A and list of path to B.

I don't know if recursive algorithm is part of the exercise but I used a simple loop.

```
pathList = [[50,10,30],[5,90,20],[40,2,25],[10,8,999999]]

def all_steps(pathList):

    stepListA,stepListB = [],[]
    for n in range(0,len(pathList)):

        #Step to A
        if pathList[n][0]<=pathList[n][1] + pathList[n][2]:#A to A
            new_stepListA = list(stepListA)
            new_stepListA.append(pathList[n][0])
        else: #B to A 
            new_stepListA = list(stepListB)
            new_stepListA.extend([pathList[n][1],pathList[n][2]])          

        #Step to B
        if pathList[n][1]<=pathList[n][2] + pathList[n][2]:#B to B
            new_stepListB = list(stepListB)
            new_stepListB.append(pathList[n][1])
        else: #A to B 
            new_stepListB = list(stepListA)
            new_stepListB.extend([pathList[n][0],pathList[n][2]])   

        stepListA = list(new_stepListA)
        stepListB = list(new_stepListB)

    if sum(stepListA)<=sum(stepListB):
        print "finish on A"
        return stepListA
    else:
        print "finish on B"
        return stepListB


print  all_steps(pathList)
```

Comment: Thanks for ideas, but it gives wrong answer `[10, 25, 2, 18]` - it cannot be an answer

Comment: Well the 999999 was misplaced and I corrected it but it is just about input data. The answer is then [10, 25, 2, 8] which seems to answer perfectly to your picture for the best path from left to right. Ifnot, please tell me what answer you expect.

Comment: From picture we can see that the shortest path is 10 30 5 20 2 8

Comment: Okay you were right, I misunderstood it. i did an error and A to B or B to A transition. Now it will work.